# output and call array from class function (rollingcurl)

Tags: php, arrays, class, curl, methods

Excuse my English, please.

I use Rollingcurl to crawl various pages.

Rollingcurl: https://github.com/LionsAd/rolling-curl

My class:

```
<?php

class Imdb
{

    private $release;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->release = "";
    }

    // SEARCH
    public static function most_popular($response, $info)
    {

        $doc = new DOMDocument();

        libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //disable libxml errors

        if (!empty($response)) {
            //if any html is actually returned

            $doc->loadHTML($response);
            libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

            $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

            //get all the h2's with an id
            $row   = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'lister-item-image') and contains(@class, 'float-left')]/a/@href");
            $nexts = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@class, 'lister-page-next') and contains(@class, 'next-page')]");
            $names = $xpath->query('//img[@class="loadlate"]');

            // NEXT URL - ONE TIME
            $Count    = 0;
            $next_url = "";
            foreach ($nexts as $next) {

                $Count++;
                if ($Count == 1) {
                    /*echo "Next URL: " . $next->getAttribute('href') . "<br/>";*/

                    $next_link = $next->getAttribute('href');
                }
            }

            // RELEASE NAME
            $rls_name = "";
            foreach ($names as $name) {
                $rls_name .= $name->getAttribute('alt');
            }

            // IMDB TT0000000 RLEASE
            if ($row->length > 0) {
                $link = "";
                foreach ($row as $row) {
                    $tt_info .= @get_match('/tt\\d{7}/is', $doc->saveHtml($row), 0);
                }
            }

        }
        $array = array(
            $next_link,
            $rls_name,
            $tt_info,
        );
        return ($array);
    }
}
```

Output/Return:

```
$array = array(
    $next_link,
    $rls_name,
    $tt_info,
);
return ($array);
```

Call:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function get_match($regex, $content, $pos = 1)
{
    /* do your job */
    preg_match($regex, $content, $matches);
    /* return our result */
    return $matches[intval($pos)];
}

require "RollingCurl.php";
require "imdb_class.php";
$imdb = new Imdb;

if (isset($_GET['action']) || isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : $_POST['action'];
} else {
    $action = "";
}

echo "  2222<br /><br />";


if ($action == "most_popular") {

    $popular = '&num_votes=1000,&production_status=released&groups=top_1000&sort=moviemeter,asc&count=40&start=1';

    if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
        $link = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature,tv_movie&release_date=,".$_GET['date'].$popular;
    } else {
        $link = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature,tv_movie&release_date=,2018".$popular;
    }

    $urls            = array($link);
    $rc              = new RollingCurl([$imdb, 'most_popular']); //[$imdb, 'most_popular']
    $rc->window_size = 20;
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $request = new RollingCurlRequest($url);
        $rc->add($request);
    }
    $stream = $rc->execute();
}
```

If I output everything as "echo" in the class, everything is also displayed. However, I want to call everything individually.

If I now try to output it like this, it doesn't work.

```
$stream[0]
$stream[1]
$stream[3]
```

Does anyone have any idea how this might work?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RollingCurl` doesn't do anything with the return value of the callback, and doesn't return it to the caller. `$rc->execute()` just returns `true` when there's a callback function. If you want to save anything, you need to do it in the callback function itself.

You should make `most_popular` a non-static function, and give it a property `$results` that you initialize to `[]` in the constructor.. Then it can do:

```
$this->results[] = $array;
```

After you do

```
$rc->execute();
```

you can do:

```
foreach ($imdb->results as $result) {
    echo "Release name: $result[1]<br>TT Info: $result[2]<br>";
}
```

It would be better if you put the data you extracted from the document in arrays rather than concatenated strings, e.g.

```
$this->$rls_names = [];
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $this->$rls_names[] = $name->getAttribute('alt');
}

$this->$tt_infos = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $this->$tt_infos[] = @get_match('/tt\\d{7}/is', $doc->saveHtml($row), 0);
}

$this->next_link = $next[0]->getAttribute('href'); // no need for a loop to get the first element of an array
```

Comment: If I provide this as non-static, then I can no longer use functions from outside as for example:  @get_match('/tt\\d{7}/is', $doc->saveHtml($row), 0)

I've only been working on it for a short time and so I'm not very fit yet.

At this point once again a big thank you, you have already helped me in advance!

Comment: Non-static methods can call outside functions just fine.

Comment: Vielen Dank:
Mit var_dump, erhalte ich nun das hier:
https://pastebin.com/6DHb1fw7

Comment: So now I'm one step further.
How do I do that, that every output like $rls_name and $tt_info is written in an extra line? Everything is lined up. With $stream[0][0] I get $next_link back as desired. Unfortunately the others are all in the same row.

Comment: Thank you very much.
How can I prevent $tt_info and $rls_name from being written in only one row?
TT-Info looks like this: tt1517451tt1213641tt0077651tt3606756tt7349662tt4154756tt1485796tt5463162tt0089218tt7668870tt4912910tt6644200tt2380307tt0107688tt0081505tt0241527tt3501632tt0120338tt2543472tt0111161tt0070047tt6499752tt1856101tt0816692tt0468569tt0068646tt5052448tt0083866tt5726616tt0110912tt0317705tt0109830tt1375666tt5027774tt0409459tt0120737tt0107290tt1345836tt0993846tt3890160

Comment: You can use string functions to split it up and print it however you like.

Comment: Is this possible with a split function?

Example:
If he finds the movie "Venom", I want the corresponding "tt0000000" to be output as well.
I was thinking of "Venom:tt0000000". Something like that.

I will try myself further.

Comment: It would be better if you structured the data more usefully in `most_popular` so you don't have to parse strings.

Comment: Good morning sir.

Can you possibly give me an example?  An example would be enough for me to be able to deal with it and hopefully implement it.  Of course I don't want to steal your time.  What I have tried so far has not worked.  The output should look something like this:  Releasename:tt0000000.  Then I can separate using explode.

Comment: I've added some examples of how to collect the data in more structured form. It should be easy for you to figure out how to print it in any format.